# Face book like button sample code for multicounty site

Tags: jakarta-ee, facebook-like

We are having three different site hosted with three different domain (.us ,.ch and .ca) . User can access the site through a single common url and based on user geoip request routed corresponding domain . We are using face book like feature in our site . when some one click on like button outside US then website link is correctly appearing on face book wall page but the image is not appearing correctly . we are guessing to load images face book sending it's own request which is from US and as it's geoip is an US based ip it's trying to load the images from US site and unable to find . Can some one help how to implement facebook like code for a multicounty supported website .
Also do i need to use three different appid for three different website in my code . Becuase in our case code is common for all the three hosted website.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one app_id across all three versions of the site.  This is a very interesting question however.  First I would try each of the three versions of the site in the debugger:  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug, and tweek your code until each of the three sites work there.  Also When someone likes the page, do you want individual counts for each version, or the total count for the three?

Comment: Hi ,Thank you for response.We want total counts of all the site to display individually on the individual site. I am trying to using same app id for the site and test using debugger tool.

Comment: How is it going using the linter tool?